# Ruby on rails installation error in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails new my_app is throwing following error

`An error occurred while installing rake 0.9.2.2 and bundle can not continue. Make sure that  gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2' succeeds before bundling.`

I've installed latest version of Ruby on Rails in window 7.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Something seems wrong with your error quotes. Please edit the question to include this data.

Comment: Did you mean the command `rails new my_app`, because `RUBY new my_app` doesn't create a new Rails app...

Comment: @Vapire +1 he is generating project with `ruby new my_project` :)

Comment: yes, i mean rails new my_app(my mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `rails new my_project` to generate your project. also run `rails -v` to ensure rails is installed